# eclipse debug perl curses

Tags: perl, debugging, console, epic

I am writing a Perl program that uses curses for output and move the cursor, and color characters. Previously, when I was working under windows I use Komodo it was able to run an external console.

Now I work in Linux environment and use eclipse + epic. If you try to just run the script, it uses the internal console eclipse, which is very cut. You can just run the script using external tool, but I'm interested to debug using external console window. Is this possible?

Unfortunately, use of a File and /dev/pty/1 does not help in solving my problem.
The fact is that in this case it is impossible to get the characters introduced in the console through curses getch(). Always returned 1 instead code of pressed key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that will take you most of the way (based on post #6 of: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=743131, although since then, in the "Indigo" and "Juno" versions of Eclipse, things have changed somewhat, and this answer is up to date):

Go to "Run -> Debug configurations".  Click on the (fourth) "Common" tab. Go to the third frame from top, and there, check-mark the checkbox which says: "File". Enter the file name of the console window you want your output in.

Comment: I tried this option. But in the console I get the following error: Error opening terminal: unknown.

Comment: And i can't use curses getch().

Comment: @shorenkov: 'Error opening terminal: unknown' may indicate that you haven't entered the right file name for the console window that you had selected